# В карточке товара

Tags: javascript, битрикс

На сайте 1с-Bitrix в карточке товара, ошибка такого вида: В соответствии с объявленной кодировкой символов поток байтов был ошибочен. Объявленная кодировка символов может быть неправильна.

Как решить эту ошибку?

Смотрел и кодировка стоит utf-8.

Можете сами заюзать для примера на этой странице https://vita-nord.ru/catalog/lekarstvennye-preparaty-i-bad/vitaminy-mineraly-obshchetonizir-preparaty/obshchetonizir-preparaty-adaptogeny/obshchetonizir-pr-ty-adaptogeny-b-rets/51926/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Такая ошибка возникает, когда подключается скрипт, который делался в другой кодировке. Комментарии сделаны в неправильной кодировке, исполнять скрипт это не мешает, но парсер всё же ругается.

Comment: То есть на работу скрипта этот никак не влияет?

Comment: В данном случае - не влияет.

Comment: Спасибо большое